# cucumber vs spinach in term of speed

Tags: cucumber, spinach

I'm evaluating cucumber for testing, but the speed of execution is too slow. I've found Spinach but am wondering how they compare speedwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a dead question, but the bottleneck for either of these is likely to be the Rails startup time, along with the driver that Capybara uses rather than any underlying differences between the test suites.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver